# Make multiple text assignments to a node with d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Hi so I'm trying to add multiple text elements to a d3 svg g node. However, for the following code, all the first text assignments to a node show up but none of the second text elements appear. Is my approach right? or is there a bug I'm missing

```
 var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

 // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
  .on("click", click);

nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  // .on("mouseenter",setdatavis)
  // .on("mouseleave",setdatainvis);

nodeEnter.append("text")
  // .attr("x",0)
  // .attr("y",0)
  // .append("tspan")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("y",-10)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .style("visibility","visible");
  // .on("mouseenter", function(){d3.select(this)
  //   .style("visibility", "hidden")
  //   .transition()                      
  //   ;})
  // .on("mouseleave", function(){d3.select(this)
  //   .style("visibility", "visible")
  //   .transition()                      
  //   ;});

nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x",10)
  .attr("text-anchor","start")
  .attr("y",10)
  .attr("dy",".35em")
  .text(function(d){return "hi";})
  .style("visibility","visible")
  .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: Here is a codeshare with all the info http://codeshare.io/ggMEg. There's a huge json in the middle, that holds the data structure that I'm performing this graph generation on

Comment: You're setting the opacity to 1e-6 and not transitioning it to 1. It's there, just not visible. You probably want `nodeUpdate.selectAll("text")` for transitioning to opacity 1.

Comment: TY!!! that worked! Do you know if there's a way to make those visibility handlers I have set at the bottom to only make the second set of text visible/invisible. Like can I assign id's to the second set of text

Comment: Yes, you can assign IDs or classes.

Comment: yeah thanks already got it to work